# ICollectionView.SortDescriptions does not work for boolean

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, boolean, collectionviewsource

myListBox.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(
            new SortDescription("BoolProperty", ListSortDirection.Descending));

This sorting works only for string properties of the underlying project. Not with boolean? Is there a reason for that ?

Thanks !

**UPDATE:**

Yep, your example really works. But what's wrong on my example ?

```
public class A
{
    public bool Prop;            
}

List<A> l = new List<A>() {
    new A() { Prop = true  }, 
    new A() { Prop = false }, 
    new A() { Prop = true  },
};

ICollectionView icw = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(l);                                                
icw.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Prop", ListSortDirection.Ascending));                
icw.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, I can seem to add a SortDescription on a boolean property in my list example!

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="box" DisplayMemberPath="Test" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //4 instances, each with a property Test of another boolean value
        box.ItemsSource = new[] {
            new {Test = true}, 
            new {Test = false}, 
            new {Test = false}, 
            new {Test = true}
        };

        box.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Test", ListSortDirection.Descending));
    }
}


public class BooleanHolder
{
    public bool Test { get; set; }
}
```

Works like a charm ;)

Perhaps you misspelled the property name in the SortDescription object? Hope this helps

In your example you defined Prop as a field. Make it a property and it will work ;)

```
public class A
{
    public bool Prop { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, your example really works, but look at mine please, I dont see a huge difference.

Comment: Prop is not a property but a field.. there lies the difference! ;)

WPF looks for properties, and does not find it!

Comment: Yeah i realized the difference meanwhile.. thank you, the field should be private anyways.. perhaps that's the reason

Comment: I thought the engine looks for the Properties AND public Fields. Well.. i should 'resharp' more :))